# Connect to a private Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I am trying to connect to a private Minecraft server of a friend of mine. I use the Windows 10 app to play and he is playing on a Mac. He can connect to the Minecraft server hosted on a cloud machine, but I can't connect to this server.

What could be the problem? Is it not possible to connect from different operating systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect with 2 different versions of the game.

**Minecraft - Windows 10 Edition**, the game you're playing, is part of the universal Minecraft game, written in C++, compatible with phones, tablets, game consoles, and Windows 10 PCs.

**Minecraft - Java Edition** is the other edition of Minecraft. This is most likely the one your friend is playing on his Mac, and more likely the one his server is compatible with.

Minecraft Java Edition and Windows 10 Edition are NOT compatible with each other. In order to play on your friend's server, you will have to download the java edition of the game [here](https://minecraft.net/).

If you don't own a copy of that version you may have to buy it.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: thanks. if I bought the windows 10 Editon i can use also the java edition or only in the other way?

Comment: @cpiock unfortunately I don't think so, but there's not much I can find online - if you really don't want to pay for it, contact Mojang support and they may be able to help.